# Test OSGi project with JUnit4

Tags: osgi, junit4

I have a maven project. I created a JUnit4 test class for one of my classes using the Idea wizard.

```
package com.mst.ica.dao.support;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DbNamingStandardTest extends TestCase {

}
```

When I tried to run my test, I got the following error in my output and nothing more.

`OSGi in module 'com.mst.ica.integration.api': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aQute/bnd/osgi/Builder`
Does anybody know what it means and how to run my test?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing JUnit 3 (TestCase) and JUnit 4 (org.junit.*).

See the osgi-test project (https://github.com/osgi/osgi-test/) which provides support libraries for testing in OSGi as well as some examples. In particular, the `org.osgi.test.junit4` has a test case which runs in OSGi using JUnit 4 (either plain JUnit4 or using the vintage engine with JUnit 5).